# Checking LTE/CDMA/GSM Modem Data Capabilities

Tags: at-command, modem, carrier

A little background:
I have a One Plus One phone currently running LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2). The SoC the phone uses is a Qualcomm MSM8974ACPro with a baseband version of 
mpss.di.3.0.c6-00241-m8974aaaaanazm-1. 
I wrote a little serial console in python which I use to issue AT commands to the device '/dev/smd11' (the modem) at 115200 baud. 
According to the response from the command 'AT+CGMM' the model number of the modem is simply '4083' from Qualcomm.

The question:
For experimental purposes I am attempting to make a call to a BBS (or any other serial data modem) through the console, to see what sort of response I can get. The command 'AT+FCLASS' returns 0,2.0 indicating the modem supports the fax class 2.0. I think that this could imply the modem has some sort of ADC capabilities. I also remember seeing v.24 and v.25 support but cant remember for the life of me which command resulted in that.

The issue arises when I place a call using the ATDxxxxxxxxxx command. I can place voice calls by appending a semicolon to the number, however it is my understanding that you need to exclude that when placing a data call. When excluded the modem immediately returns a 'NO CARRIER' message.

So, is there a way to verify what I am doing is possible? I am looking for less of a yes or no answer but rather other commands that could help me better understand my phone's modem or if I am wrong in my command usage, what I should do to correct it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Testing `AT+FCLASS` is a bit unrelated when you actually want to test for support of CSD, circuit switched data (actually [NTCSD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42890927/23118)). So to check for that the first command to check support for is `AT+RLP` because that contains CSD protocol parameters, and must be present when a modem supports NTCSD. The `AT+CBST` command is mandatory for any type of data call support.

If those two are unsupported, your modem does not support CSD.

As a bonus I give you a list of all the other commands that are related to CSD calls (excluding those that are common with voice calls, e.g. `AT+CLIP` etc):
All the HSCSD (High Speed Circuit Switched Data) commands:
AT+CHSN, AT+CHSD, AT+CHSC, AT+CHSR, AT+CHSU, AT+CHSA.
as well as 
AT+DS
AT+CR
AT+ILRR
AT+V120
and 
ATO.

You can by the way list all available commands with `AT+CLAC` (optinal command, but usually implemented).

For the case when you get `NO CARRIER` you could try to enable extended error reporting with `AT+CMEE=2`, although that typically does not affect `ATD`.

Comment: The 'at+rsp' command only returns an ERROR indicating that the command isn't supported. However the command 'at+cbst?' returns (0,0,1) and 'at+cbst=?' Returns (0,7,12,14,16,17,39,43,48,51,71,75,80,81,83,84,116,134),(0,1,4),(0,1). So evidently I can select a sbt. After enabling the extended error reporting I still only receive 'no carrier' from the ATD call. It would seem like the capabilities exist outside of the 'at+rlp' command. Very strange, outside of the ATD command. Do you know of any neccesary combination of commands to configure the modem prior to a data call?

Comment: I spoke to soon, 'at+rlp' doesn't exist but 'at+crlp' does. 'At+crlp=?' Returns
+CRLP: (0-61),(0-61),(38-255),(1-255),0

+CRLP: (0-61),(0-61),(38-255),(1-255),1

+CRLP: (0-488),(0-488),(42-255),(1-255),2.

Comment: That is good news with regards to supporting NTCSD, because it clearly does. RLP version 0 and 1 are identical except that version 1 implies V.42bis compression (controlled by `AT+DS`). Version 2 supports speeds higher than 9600 and is required for HSCSD.

Comment: FYI: The phone will automatically negotiate the RLP version to use with the MSC in the network, based on how the call is configured, e.g. a plain 9600 can be version 0, 1 or 2, while HSCSD speeds require version 2. RLP version cannot change during a call, so if the call starts version 2 and the mobile hands over to a network only supporting version 0/1 then the call will be dropped.